# How to align equations properly

Tags: amsmath, alignment, alignat

[image]

[edited since I figured out some stuff on my own and to add an MWE]
How do I make the x in the second line be centred with the x + n in the first like in the picture? Also there's probably something wrong with my use of & and && since it makes the spacing very narrow. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,kpfonts}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    && \floor{x} & \le x + n & < & \floor{x + n} + 1\\
    \leadsto\quad && \floor{x + n} - n & \le x & < & \floor{x + n} - n + 1 \\
    \leadsto\quad && \floor{x} & = & & \floor{x + n} - n\\
    \leadsto\quad && \floor{x + n} & = & & \floor{x} + n
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the code of your equation part, hence no one like to keyin your text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the original has been obtained with `array`.

If you want to use `alignat` you need a further alignment point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,kpfonts}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
              && \floor{x}         & \le x + n && <{} && \floor{x + n} + 1\\
\leadsto\quad && \floor{x + n} - n & \le x     && <{} && \floor{x + n} - n + 1 \\
\leadsto\quad && \floor{x}         & =         &&     && \floor{x + n} - n\\
\leadsto\quad && \floor{x + n}     & =         &&     && \floor{x} + n
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `<{}` in order to get the correct spacing.

However, that proof of ⌊*x* + *n*⌋ = ⌊*x*⌋ + *n* isn't very appealing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,kpfonts}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}

Starting from $\floor{x}\le x<\floor{x}+1$, we deduce that, for any integer~$n$,
\[
\floor{x}+n\le x+n<\floor{x}+n+1
\]
and, since $\floor{x}+n$ is integer, we conclude that
\[
\floor{x}+n=\floor{x+n}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]